# How can Continuity Camera in iOS 16 be controlled with Shortcuts?

Tags: camera, shortcuts-app, continuity

I want to turn Continuity Camera on and off with a shortcut. (It uses too much battery, so it's best left off except when I want to use it.) I can find no mention of such control anywhere.

How can Continuity Camera in iOS 16 be controlled with Shortcuts?

Comment: If you're not actually using the camera, does it really use significant battery?

Comment: Yes, it still uses significant battery. Tons of it. In just a few hours, Continuity Camera becomes the top consumer by a wide margin. It's something like 50% versus the second place consumer at around 30% (very rough numbers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can continuity camera in ios 16 be controlled with Shortcuts?

Unfortunately, you can’t.

[Apple details the methods](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213244) of how to pause, mute, or disconnect your iPhone from continuity, and only one refers to doing this via your Mac:

> Use your app's controls to stop video, mute audio, or end the call. Or quit the app.

All other methods are via the iPhone itself. This explains the lack of shortcuts as there are none that allow you to control apps in the manner nor quit an application.

As for the battery, you can disconnect the device using the methods described by Apple or simply plug in via your USB cable.  If connected, it will be continually charging as it’s connected.